# Bottle Sizes Smaller than 12 Ounces?

Tags: equipment, bottling

Has anyone ever seen 8oz bottles anywhere?  I was asked if I could bottle a batch of homebrew in smaller bottles so it could be given out as gifts to more people.  I can't seem to find anything smaller than 12oz.

Comment: Just a side note here: you might want to prime a bit more if using smaller bottles. The proportion of head space to liquid seems to determine the carbonation level of the beer.  My quarts and 22's always come out more carbonated than my 12 ozers. If I was to bottle in something smaller than 12 oz, I would definitely up my priming sugar.

Answer (score 3):

I found some 6oz bottles are Seven Bridges Ograninc Brewing in Santa Cruz, Ca.

[6 Fl. 0z. Bottles](http://www.breworganic.com/browseproducts/6-oz.-Mini-Champagne-Bottles--Case-of-24.html)

Comment: nice!  I wonder if anyone makes amber ones, though.

Comment: Yeah, I couldn't find any.  But I bet if you called Seven Bridges, they mught be able to get a lead on them.  MoreBeer.com also had the same thing, but they were out of stock.  Again a phone call may get you what you want.

Answer (score 3):

Malta Goya (a non-alcoholic malt based drink) can be purchased in 7oz brown glass bottles; I'm pretty sure that they're pry-top bottles.  It's fairly widely available, and can often be had for less than 50 cents a bottle.

Here's a picture:
[image: Malta soft drink photo, Wikimedia Commons.]

Comment: Is it carbonated?  If not then the bottle might not hold pressure.  Otherwise, it looks good as long as you have a bench capper (a hand-held capper likely won't be able to grip the neck on that)

Comment: From this picture, the bottle appears to be screw-top.

Answer (score 0):

There is a beer call Little Kings (cream ale) that comes in a 7oz green bottle in an 8 pack. I have never had it before but thought of making a purchase for the same reason. Little sample bottle would be nice. A number of manufacturers offer 11.2 oz bottles but I doubt that helps based on what your looking for.

Comment: Little Kings beer is made by Hudepohl-Schoenling Brewing Co. out of Ohio.

Answer (score 0):

Corsendonk Christmas Ale comes in ~8 ounce bottles.  The foil wrapper around the neck is kind of hard to get off, but I think it's totally worth it to have some small bottles on hand.  I use them for testing carbonation levels when the beer is young.  If it's not ripe yet I only "wasted" 8 ounces and not 12, 16, or 22 ounces.

(I say "wasted" in quotes because I'm definitely drinking it nonetheless.)

Answer (score 0):

yes I found them at Midwest supplies.  They are just a bit smaller than 7 ounces though...about 5+ ounces.  24.99 for 24 bottles